# How to bind parametres dynamically in php?

Tags: php, mysql

What I'm trying to do is to build a search function in php to fetch data from mysql database.

**The problem** is that the query is dynamically generated based on user input.
I have several input fields in a form matching a search parameter, for example I can search for the name or the year of the product (separated input forms) or I can search only for the name or only for the year.

I succeed building the SQL query and I can successfully pass values for a valid select statement.

**But** I want to prevent SQL injection with parametrized queries.

This is the piece of code I use to generate the query:

```
$searchKeyword = $_POST['searchKeyWord'];
$year = $_POST['searchYear'];
$location = $_POST['searchLocation'];
$alcool = $_POST['alcol'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM CAPS WHERE 1";

if($searchKeyword != null) {
    $query.=" and name like '%$searchKeyword%' ";
}

if($year != null) {
    $query.="and year='$year' ";
}

if($location != null) {
    $query.="and location like '%$location%' ";
}

if($alcool != "none") {
    $query.=" and alcool='$alcool'";
}
```

It builds the query as is should, I can have only one field with input and it will be something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM CAPS 
WHERE 1  
  AND name LIKE '%Cola%'`
```

or it can also be

```
SELECT * 
FROM CAPS 
WHERE 1 
  AND name LIKE '%Cola%' 
  AND year = '1999' 
  AND location LIKE '%London%'
```

My question is: if I replace the '$variable' in the query with '?', how do I insert the input based of the generated query?

Comment: What do you mean by $variable? Is it searchKeyword, year, location, alcool?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean $variable = $searchKeyword or $year or $location or $alcool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is susceptible for SQL injections.

Since you know all the fields and operations you're allowing for a search, use a whitelist

```
/*
fieldname => operator
*/
$allowed = [
    'alcool'   => 'like',
    'location' => 'like',
    'year'     => '=',
    'name'     => 'like',
];

// fake input (one unknown field)
$_POST['alcool']   = 'tee';
$_POST['location'] = 'home';
$_POST['password'] = 'hello';

$fields     = [];
$queryParts = [];
$parameters = [];
foreach($allowed as $field => $op) {
    if (isset($_POST[ $field ])) {
        $fields[] = $field;
        $value = $_POST[ $field ];
        if ($op == 'like') { // prepare string for LIKE '%...%'
            $value = sprintf('%%%s%%', $value); // => 
        }
        $queryParts[] = sprintf('`%s` %s ?', $field, $op);
        $parameters[] = $value;
    }
}

$searchSql = sprintf('SELECT id, alcool, location, year, ... FROM table WHERE %s', implode(' AND ', $queryParts));

echo $searchSql . PHP_EOL;
print_r($parameters);
```

The output :

```
SELECT id, alcool, location, year, ... FROM table WHERE `alcool` like ? AND `location` like ?
Array
(
    [0] => %tee%
    [1] => %home%
)
```

Use with PDO (or whatever driver you're using)

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($searchSql);
if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->execute($parameters);
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        // your results...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! With a little bit of tweaks here and there I managed to do it! You are a hero!

Comment: Additionally I recommend escaping the `LIKE` value to ensure the `%` symbols in the `$_POST` value, such as `100%` does not conflict with the `WHERE` clause.  `$value = sprintf('%%%s%%', str_replace('%', '\\%', $value));` to result in `%100\%%`

Answer (score 0):

While the solution by Lars solves your problem, it does not explicitly answer the question you asked. There are scenarios where it is helpful to have a static query statement with substitutions at run time. Examples include cases where there is a high cost of generating explain plans and where you use a stored procedure for privilege seperation, although it should be noted that this approach will not be able to use indexes as effectively as building the query dynamically:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CAPS 
WHERE name like '%$searchKeyword%'
AND   location like '%$location%'
AND   ( '' = '$year' OR year='$year')
AND   ( '' = '$alcool' OR alcool='$alcool');
```

(I've left the variable names in the query rather than placeholders for clarity)